# Implement the jQuery animate function on a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Hello I'm trying to convert a normal JQuery code into a javascript object to create multiple instances of a slider but every time I execute the "animate function" from within a method it pops an "undefined is not an object" error in the console" can anybody help me with that?
Here is the code:

```
function ObjSlider(velocidad,pausa,idSlider){
    this.velAnim = velocidad;
    this.pausa = pausa;
    $(".slide:first-child").clone().appendTo($(".slides"));
    this.$slider = $(idSlider);
    this.$contSlides = this.$slider.find(".slides");
    this.$slides = this.$contSlides.find(".slide");
    this.totalSlides = this.$slides.length;
    this.currentSlide = 1;
    this.anchoSlide = $(".slider .slides .slide").width();
}
ObjSlider.prototype.sliderOn = function(){
    this.intervalo = setInterval(function(){
    this.$contSlides.animate({"margin-left":"-="+this.anchoSlide},this.velAnim,function(){
        this.currentSlide++;
        if(this.currentSlide === this.totalSlides){
            this.currentSlide = 1;
            this.$contSlides.css("margin-left",0);
        }
    });
    }, this.pausa);
};
```

and then to create the new object:

```
var slider1 = new ObjSlider(1000,3000,'#sliderTop');
slider1.sliderOn();
```

Thank you very much guys

cheers

Comment: In which line does that error appear and what is that corresponding line in the provided code snippet?

Comment: Thanks for the response. it appears in the line 18 of my browser when I test it and it corresponds to the line 14 of the snippet I posted here. Right where it says: `this.$contSlides.animate({`

Comment: Well it seems I found the solution it was just a matter of taking some the properties in the constructor and placing them as variables on the method. Thanks anyways

Comment: It would be great if you could post your own solution as an answer and accept it, for others who might find this question to benefit from.

Comment: `Slider.prototype.slideOn = function(){
 var $contSlides = $(this.idSlides);
 var ancho = this.anchoSlide;
 totalSlides = $contSlides.find(".slide");
 totalSlides = totalSlides.length;
 intervalo = setInterval(function(){
 $contSlides.animate({"margin-left":"-="+ancho},this.velAnim,function(){
  currentSlide++;
  if(currentSlide === totalSlides){
   currentSlide = 1;
   $contSlides.css("margin-left",0);
  }
 });
}, this.pausa);
};`